# List function callers in Atom

Tags: go, editor, atom-editor, go-to-definition

I write Go code in Atom. I see a feature is go/jump to Definition function. But I want to view/show a list of callers to this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [go-plus](https://atom.io/packages/go-plus) package.

It has desired feature: `Find usages of an identifier using guru`

guru: a tool for answering questions about Go source code.

Comment: But I see it is very slow.

Comment: @kienbui afair it still doesn't support caching, so each `find usage` rescans tree, you might be interested in [Intellij Gogland](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/), as all Intellij products it supports indexing, but I might be wrong